# Laravel 4.2 form Route POST error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I've been using Laravel for a while now, although with a new install I did I cannot get the routes POST working, Routes GET works just fine but not post.
It keeps throwing a MethodNotAllowedHttpException error.
This is my routes

`Route::post('/admin/new_event', [
    "as" => "admin.event_add",
    "uses" => "AdminController@adminEventAddPost"
]);`

This is my form

`<form action="{{ URL::route("admin.event_add") }}" method="POST">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Event Title" name="title"><br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Event Detail" name="detail"><br/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn purp-button">Post</button>
</form>`

this is the controller

```
   public function adminEventAddPost()
{

    $title = Input::get("title");
    $detail = Input::get("detail");
    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    Events::create([
        "title" => $title,
        "detail" => $detail,
        "date" => $date
    ]);
    return Redirect::route("admin.events_new");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `{{csrf_field()}}` to your form.

Comment: I added that then it said the var was not found. Tried that last night. I've read so many different pages relaitng CSRF but cannot get it working.

Comment: Call to undefined function csrf_field()

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this if you haven't

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

It's about the CSRF Protection.

Like Algridas said in his answer but i think you are using an older version of laravel and you might need to use

```
@csrf
```

Comment: Added that, but instead of not showing like the other on page commands like @foreach - It actually just prints as text on the form element

Comment: I also tried this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">` 
But it still doesn't work

Comment: @CasperRound sorry for the late reply , did you try {{@csrf}} ?